# Set ColdFusion variables in JS for use in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am trying to toggle a dynamic number of divs if a user clicks a little pencil glyph. I'm setting the IDs for the glyph and the hidden divs as "pencilX" and "hiddenY" where X and Y correspond to the autoincrementing ID as stored in the database. Here is the code I have:

I will loop through the query of items in the table outputting this code for each item, so that the user can click a different pencil for each item and it will show toggle the div containing the info for that item.

My research so far is pointing me in the direction of having to use AJAX, but I don't understand AJAX very well and I'm wondering if it's really necessary here. I know I can't access the CF variables directly from jQuery, so I'm wondering if I can just set the variables in JS from the CF side before it hits the client, as I am trying to do below. But of course it isn't working!

I have also tried using the ToScript function which isn't working either. jQuery doesn't seem to recognize either.

```
<cfoutput>
<!---Query huddle item, set div ID--->
<cfquery name="huddleItem" datasource="LPKCMA">
    SELECT *
    FROM CMA_COMM_HDDL
    WHERE ID = 1
</cfquery>
<cfset pencilID = "##pencil" & huddleItem.ID>
<cfset hiddenID = "##hidden" & huddleItem.ID>
<!---Div toggle--->
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--- Didn't work
    var #toScript(pencilID, "pencil")#;
    var #toScript(hiddenID, "hidden")#;
--->
    var pencil = '#pencilID#';
    var hidden = '#hiddenID#';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#' + pencil).click(function(){
            $('#' + hidden).toggle('fast');
        });
    });
</script>
<!--- Content below including pencil and div... --->
```

Comment: I solved this. The CF variable I was setting included the escaped pound sign, which was being passed to the IDs of the div and pencil themselves.

Comment: You should write that up as the answer

Comment: Just a suggestion for the next time you ask a question, don't simply say something "didn't work": explain how you expected it to work, and how the actual result differed from your expectations. It will make it easier for the people trying to help. Also, going through this process often helps solving the problem before needing to ask for help. Suggested reading: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html (including the docs linked to).